# C++11 pass vector to constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, constructor

I'm reading all day long about the best efficient way to pass arguments and I'm confused. I want to pass a vector like this:

```
Foo f({1,2,3});
```

I just to want to initialize my **_member** variable with the passed vector. Now the question is how should my constructor look:

```
// pass by value
Foo (vector<int> vec) : _member{vec} {}

// const reference
Foo (const vector<int>& vec) : _member{vec} {}

// rvalue reference
Foo (vector<int>&& vec) : _member{std::move(vec)} {}
```

Comment: Your pass-by-value should have an `std::move` as well

Comment: initialize new vector as vector<int>  and pass it

Comment: Please do not destroy your posts. If you don't want the post to be associated with you anymore, [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239366/could-we-have-a-help-center-page-on-disassociating-posts)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest approach is to take the vector by value, and move it:

```
Foo (vector<int> vec) : _member{std::move(vec)} {}
```

Compared to a pair of `const vector<int>&`/`vector<int>&&` overloads, you pay up to one extra move (which is very cheap for vectors), but don't have to write two constructors (which can explode quite quickly if you have more than one parameter).

Comment: What do you mean by 'extra' move? As compared to what?

Comment: @Petrof This works equally well for small and large vectors.

Comment: @Petrof By value vs. by rvalue reference are equally efficient for temporaries (due to elision). If you want to make constructing `Foo` with an lvalue vector an error, then use rvalue reference.

Answer (score 3):

Pass by value is trendy nowadays in many circles. I think it's a good choice for constructors for various reasons, so I agree with T.C.'s answer. However, the broader question of the best way to pass arguments (to non-constructor functions), I rarely recommend pass by value. I really, really strongly recommend listening to this portion of a talk from Herb Sutter on the topic: https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=51m34s.

To summarize, outside of constructors: pass by value gives worse worst-case performance guarantees compared to simple pass by const-ref, it gives worse performance than const-ref/rvalue-ref overloads in all cases, it makes it harder to give exception guarantees, it slices polymorphic types, it can't be used when copying is conditional.

In most situations, you either don't care about performance within reason, or you care a lot. In the first case, using const-ref is simpler and easier. In the second case, pass by value isn't good enough. Again, keep in mind that constructors are different for a couple of different reasons (they are move constructing things instead of move assigning, they take many arguments which strongly affects the number of overloads you need).

Unfortunately there isn't such an easy single answer to this question. Ultimately both approaches are good enough, but I think to master C++ you want to know the pros and cons of both.

Comment: "*pass by value gives worse worst-case performance guarantees compared to simple pass by const-ref*" Unless you need a copy anyway; Sutter says the exact same thing. "*it gives worse performance than const-ref/rvalue-ref overloads in all cases*" Only by the cost of one move in many cases, but it always costs twice the code. "*it makes it harder to give exception guarantees*" Actually, it makes them easier because the burden is shifted to the caller. "*it slices polymorphic types*" Entirely orthogonal issue. "*it can't be used when copying is conditional*" See point one.

Comment: Conditionality and polymorphism are just extra special cases to keep in your head, so they make things more complicated. Usually, performance is not critical, and when performance is not critical, const ref should be your default go to. As for performance, that is *not* what Sutter says. Sutter compares copy construction (pass-by-value) to copy assignment (pass-by-const-ref); and notes that in many practical use cases for common types (vector/string) copy assignment is *significantly* cheaper. In other words: pass by value is clearly worse if we ignore perf, and it's not great for perf either.

Comment: @ildjarn Actually, you are incorrect about exception guarantees. If you have a function ``void f(std::vector<double> x, std::unique_ptr<int> y)``, you have a function that by its signature can never offer the noexcept or strong guarantees in a meaningful way. Yes, "technically" the exception isn't thrown by the function body so it can be marked noexcept, but this is pretty absurd (as Sutter also mentions). If you wrote the same function to take by const ref and rvalue ref, you can meaningfully offer any guarantees you need to, based on how the body is written.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you are passing an `rvalue` so the third choice is the best.

Comment: Because one caller represents every caller?

Comment: Of course not, but since he is providing a specific example I believe it' s nice to also have the example-specific best option.